# API returns null for files

Tags: php, directus

I'm using Directus for a headless CMS. I have been uploading a file through the Directus App but the API returns `null` for the file field.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi,Welcome to StackOverflow, for questions please adhere to stack overflow standards and provide code samples , stacktrace etc .

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan it's about some configuration that dismissed,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the latest version of Directus, apparently there is a bug that completely blows up the File field. The files get uploaded but it doesn't get linked to the field.

https://github.com/directus/api/issues/1015

It should be fixed in the next build.

Comment: what can i do now ? just waiting ?! :)

Comment: New version just came out https://github.com/directus/directus/releases/tag/190621A I just upgraded and it seems to work now. Upgrade instructions here: https://docs.directus.io/guides/upgrading.html

Answer (score 3):

*(I can't comment due to reputation)*

Are you ensuring this is an authenticated call, if you would like to make this a public call so anyone can access it (IE: A website frontend), then you might want to allow public `READ` access to `directus_files`.

Comment: I enabled it in Setting > Role and Permission > Public > System collection and then allowed read of files

Comment: this is public api

Comment: Has the file actually been saved in the entry you're requesting? I know there's an existing bug where files aren't being saved properly to a field.

Are you requesting the `files` endpoint, or your own collection with a related file?

Comment: I access it within [project]/_/files?access_token=[token], I guess did not attach file to item ?!

Comment: I requesting collection only without any parameter

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `fields` parameter](https://docs.directus.io/api/reference.html#fields) to get nested relational files. If the API is public and the file returns `null`, please verify that the public role has read access to the `directus_files` collection.